# fake crc32 (add 4 bytes in the end of the file)

Tags: c++, binary, crc32

I'm trying to fake the needed CRC32, I have found the app called PEid, so it has a plugin called crc32 that can do this

[image]

as you can see the CRC of the file is 0x97B9850E, I need 0x73CBFFB5
when I click to fix it, the app will append 0xA6D43474 to the file, and crc32 will become 0x73CBFFB5
I found the source code for this plugin:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    unsigned long c, c2, p2, pol = 0xEDB88320;

    long n, k;

    

    {

        printf("CRC32 Adjuster (c) 2001 by RElf @ HHT/2\n");

        printf("Length of data: "); scanf_s("%ld", &n);

        printf("Offset to patch: "); scanf_s("%ld", &k);

        n = (n - k) << 3;

        printf("Current CRC32: 0x"); scanf_s("%x", &c);

        printf("Desired CRC32: 0x"); scanf_s("%x", &c2);

        c ^= c2;

        p2 = (pol << 1) | 1;

        while (n--) if (c & 0x80000000) c = (c << 1) ^ p2; else c <<= 1;

printf("XOR masks:%02X%02X%02X%02X\n", c & 0xff, (c >> 8) & 0xff, (c >> 16) & 0xff, c >> 24);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it in C++ .net visual studio, and what the console gave me ( i put all data as length of the file 3436 and offset to patch and crc32 columns by myself):

```
CRC32 Adjuster (c) 2001 by RElf @ HHT/2
Length of data: 3436
Offset to patch: 0
Current CRC32: 0x97B9850E
Desired CRC32: 0x73CBFFB5
XOR masks:1606010E
```

why it gives me the XOR masks "0x1606010E" when it should be "0xA6D43474", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it mean to fake the needed CRC? If you have the data that the CRC protects, then you should be able to calculate it easily. What's the problem?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Guessing here: OP modified the data and wants whatever it is that is reading it to accept it as untampered with.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah it took me a second, pretty sure you're right. OP: what you're saying is you found a tool, and you found the source code for that tool, and you want to know why the functionality of both differs?

Comment: The calculated CRC will differ depending on the polynomial. Are you sure you're using the same polynomial in your compiled code as the application was using?

Comment: Also just the header of this plugin and the first line printed by your code indicate to me that this is not the source code for this plugin. One is by Gelios, the other is by RElf.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out when you would need to modify data to have a particular CRC. If you're a MITM attack you'd just discard the old message, create your own, and put your CRC on it. Unless the CRC is digitally signed or something, but then why isn't the whole message... agh I really am in over my head here and missing some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case it is appending four bytes to the file to get the desired CRC. The result is a file of length 3440. In the second case it is telling you that you can exclusive-or the *first four bytes* of the file (you gave it offset 0) with the provided constant to get the desired CRC, keeping the file length of 3436.

You can get the bytes to append by first appending four zero bytes to the file, getting the CRC of that (`0x7d096252`), and giving it that CRC, the CRC you want, and the length 3440 and offset to patch 3436 (i.e. write over those last four zeros):

```
CRC32 Adjuster (c) 2001 by RElf @ HHT/2
Length of data: 3440
Offset to patch: 3436
Current CRC32: 0x7d096252
Desired CRC32: 0x73CBFFB5
XOR masks:a6d43474
```

An alternative is [spoof](https://github.com/madler/spoof), which allows you to provide the locations of a scattered set of bits anywhere in the input that spoof can flip in order to get the desired CRC. It also permits any CRC definition, not just the usual CRC-32.